# Parts of Plot3D / ListPlot3D obscured by non-transparent tick labels (v10.0.1)

Tags: graphics

I am running *v10.0.1* on *Win7 64*.

There appears to be a problem with rendering 3-d graphics. For example:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}]
```

Parts of this toward the lower right corner are just blank white rectangles cutting out part of the surface.  They appear (by moving the view point around with the mouse) to be the background rectangles of the x and y axes tick labels which for some reason are not set to be transparent.

Has anyone else seen this on the same or on a different platform?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Linux. Can you add a screenshot by any chance?

Comment: I'm not sure how.  Can't get the uploader to install, are there any manual methods?

Comment: You could add a imgur link to your question.

Comment: I don't see this on OS X 10.9.5

Comment: I don't see this on Win8.1

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu, but for me, the greek characters look [really f***ed up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kl1O.png)